# How do I copy & move a FORM to a folder in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to create a file into a folder (or rather move when talking about a spreadsheet, since we can not create them directly. Or can we?

So my questions:

**1) I created a form in my script, how do I move it to a sub folder?**

I've tried:

```
var formFile = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId());
folder.createFile(formFile.getBlob());
DriveApp.removeFile(formFile);
```

but I received an error that I could not create a pdf file from a form.

**2) Is there a way to create a spreadsheet directly into a folder?**

All I found was this:

```
// create the file in the root
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(title + " (Response)");

// get a file (not a spreadsheet)
var ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadSheet.getId());

// copy the file into the folder
folder.createFile(ssFile.getBlob());

// delete the file from the root folder.
DriveApp.removeFile(ssFile);
```

There must be an easier way.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Form responses out of the Form, and then put them into a new spreadsheet file?

Comment: No, what I want is to create a form and a spreadsheet to receieve the reposonses. But I would like to group each from/spreadsheet into a folder rather than put everything in the drive root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new Form (Or other type of) file directly in a folder with the ***Advanced Drive Service***.
When the Drive Service is enabled, the manifest file (appsscript.json) will include `dependencies` and `enabledAdvancedServices` settings.

### appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

### Code

```
function createNewFile(po) {
  var fileResource,folderID,name,newFile,theID;

  /*
    po.folderId - ID of the folder
    po.fileName - Name of the new file
  */

  folderID = po.folderId ? po.folderId : "my_Default_FolderID_Here";
  name = po.fileName ? po.fileName : "My_Default_File_Name";

  fileResource = {
    title: name,
    "parents": [{'id':folderID}],  //<--By setting this parent ID to the folder's ID, it creates this file in the correct folder.
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.form'
  };

  newFile = Drive.Files.insert(fileResource);

  theID = newFile.getId();//get the ID of the new spreadsheet file
  //Logger.log('theID: ' + theID);
  return theID;
}
```

The Drive Service is enabled from the code editor.  In the legacy code editor, click the "Resources" menu, and choose Advanced Google Services.  In the new editor the word "Advanced" is not used, it's just Drive Service.

If you want to get all the form responses out of a form, you'll need to use code something like this:

```
function getResponsesOutOfForm() {
  var frm = FormApp.openById('My_Form_ID');
  var allResponses = frm.getResponses();
  var arrayOfData = [], rowArray = [], theResponse, formResponse, itemResponses;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < allResponses.length; i++) {
    formResponse = allResponses[i];
    itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    
    rowArray = []; //Reset inner array
    
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      theResponse = itemResponses[j].getResponse();
      rowArray.push(theResponse);
    };
    
    arrayOfData.push(rowArray);
  };

  Logger.log(arrayOfData)
  return arrayOfData;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, the first part was what i was looking for.
Is there a way to do the same with Forms as you showed for the spreadsheet creation directly in a folder?

Comment: Change `'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'` to `'application/vnd.google-apps.form'`   Replace the word "spreadsheet" with "form".  If this answers your question, you can click the green check mark to mark it as correct.

Comment: The base code to create a form in a particular folder also results in the insertion of a blank 'item' / 'question'????  I ran var folderID = 'myFolderID_Here';

var fileResource = {
  title: 'myNewFile',
  "parents": [{'id':folderID}],  //<--By setting this parent ID to the folder's ID, it creates this file in the correct folder.
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.form'
};

var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(fileResource);  return; and I have a form in the correct place but with a dummy question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the need is -

1. Create a copy of a given Google Form
2. Create a new Spreadsheet and set it as a destination of responses
3. Make a new folder for every set of Form and Sheet and place them both inside it.

```
function createTestWFSFolder() {

// These variables can be passed as parameters to this function to make it more modular.
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XJYb6of3fvHGUHFYnvsmEGrCkbIeUHPhHElpD7SJr7I/edit";
    var folderName = "New Google Form - Sheet Pair";
    var formFileName = "New Google Form";
    
    
//  Create a separate folder called "Surveys" for Google Forms being created by this app script - 
//  Checks if "Surveys" folder already exists, if not a new folder is created and the folder's id is grabbed.
    var allFormsFolderId = "";
    if (!(DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Surveys").hasNext())) {
        Logger.log("Forms Folder not found! Creating one.");
        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId());
        allFormsFolderId = parentFolder.createFolder("Surveys").getId();
    } else {
        allFormsFolderId = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Surveys").next().getId();
        Logger.log("WF Surveys Folder found! ", allFormsFolderId);
    }
    
//  Make New Google Form - Sheet pair folder inside "Surveys" Folder
    var newFormSheetFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(allFormsFolderId).createFolder(folderName).getId();
    
//   Make a copy of the input Google Form and paste it inside the New Google Form - Sheet pair folder
    var googleFormId = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(url)).makeCopy(DriveApp.getFolderById(newFormSheetFolderId)).getId();
    var googleForm = FormApp.openById(googleFormId);

//  Create a new Spreadsheet, set Google Form responses to it and move it inside the Survey Folder 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Spreadsheet for Google Form").getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(ss).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(newFormSheetFolderId));
    googleForm.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss);
}


function getIdFromUrl(url) {
return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
}
```