# How do I create a google form template using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a google form which I would like to convert to a template. The objective is to to distribute this template to other people so they can amend the form as they see fit. I also need these amended forms to sit inside a directory in the google drive.

How can I construct a google script to convert the original form into a template?

Thus far I have

```
var form = FormApp.openById('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfFORMIDGOESHEREfasdfasdfa');
```

I am stuck on how to take this form and now convert it to a template.

Comment: Do you want to see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400790/how-do-i-copy-move-a-form-to-a-folder-in-google-apps-script) solves it?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to a template"? Do you want to publish it to the template gallery? Ref. [Create a file from a template](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148833?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole form and then transform it into a template to modify it at will, it is not feasible. But instead, if you want to get certain elements and modify them or create a new form using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) you can check the [Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form), which gives you several methods that will allow you to insert or removes elements.